# How do i make this UIAlert appear

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to make an alert by pressing a button "delete data". My button is in a view which is inside a navigation controller. Here is my current code

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func deleteData(sender: UIButton) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "delete Data", message: "Do you want to delete the data", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    }
}
```

But is gives me the following error:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

Comment: You are not presenting the alert, do that first. Then, you also need to store the alert object somewhere until it has disappeared.

Comment: If he presents the alert controller it will be retained by it's presenting view controller!

Comment: Actually, it doesn't need to be stored as long as it is part of the presentation stack.

Answer (score 2):

You've created your alert view controller but you still need to present it:

```
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can read an article on the topic on [appcoda.com](http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/)

Answer (score 0):

for showing alert use:

```
self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and for dismiss use:

```
alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
```